# Linq Lambda expression OrderBY on a ThenInclude clause

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a query on an object that has a collection. I need to sort on a value in the collection. How can I use an OrderBY clause on a property of the collection?

```
                var v = await _context.CollectionA
                    .Include(x => x.CollectionB).ThenInclude(x => x.CollectionC)
```

I am hoping to sort on a property that exists on CollectionC

accomplish something like...

```
.OrderBy(x => x.ObjectA.CollectionB.CollectionC.Ordinal)
```

Comment: Answer simple question, how to order by collection?

Comment: That's a good question to get me to understand my problem better and why what I am looking for does not exist.

I need the elements in the collection to sort in a certain order. If it was SQL, I would join to a second table and orderby a column in that second table.


i.e. I am not sorting by a collection. I am trying to sort by a property in the elements of that collection.

Comment: Write down the SQL and I'll help you to write LINQ query.

Comment: great, thank you.

expecting one row from TableA and 4 Rows from TableB and C and the rows are in Order by the column in Table C.

select
 *
 from TableA a
 inner join TableB q on a.Id = q.TableAId
 inner join TableC aq on q.Id = aq.TableBId
 where a.Id = 'E9A72ED4-AA6A-4DE8-956B-0002E8D0A9E8'
 order by aq.Ordinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var query = _context.CollectionA
   .Include(x => x.CollectionB)
   .ThenInclude(x => x.CollectionC.OrderBy(c => c.Ordinal));
```

Eager Loading has no direct SQL translation, but I think it is what you need.